# Why won't Safari 5 sort an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, safari

Anyone know why Safari 5 (Windows 7) can't sort arrays of objects?

```
var arr = [{a:1},{a:3},{a:2}];
console.log(arr[0].a+','+arr[1].a+','+arr[2].a);
arr.sort(function(a,b){return a.a > b.a;});
console.log(arr[0].a+','+arr[1].a+','+arr[2].a);
```

The console result should be

```
1,3,2
1,2,3
```

This works fine in FF and IE but Safari returns:

```
1,3,2
1,3,2
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your comparison function is wrong:

```
function(a,b){return a.a > b.a;}
```

The function is expected to return negative, zero or positive depending on whether a < b, a = b or a > b. Your function returns a boolean indicating whether a > b. Try something like:

```
function(a,b){return a.a - b.a;}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It's really a mixed blessing that some browsers are gracious and others rigid...

Comment: @Marc: Actually I believe you were lucky with this small set of numbers; your original function returned only 2 of 3 possible answers, so it would have failed on IE/FF as well with a larger set.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox will accept true or false, Safari doesn't.

Comment: @TJ.: Do you have a reference for this? If this were true, it is certainly non-standard behaviour (not defined in ECMAScript) and I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: @casablanca I first thought Safari was behaving bad, which is how I got to your answer. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/DU6hY/4/. Safari (5.1.2) leaves the array in its original order. Firefox (11) and Chrome (17) handle as **falsly** expected and sort the array.

Comment: @TJ.: Interesting, I assume the boolean is being converted to a 1 or 0 and interpreted as a > b or a = b.

Comment: You can also do `return a.a > b.a ? 1:-1` where necessary

Comment: @MachineElf would that not add another condition? therefore make the sorting a little slower?

Comment: @Val I've forgotten why I posted that! I think I just meant it's possible to use a condition operator here if useful, eg for comparing floating points or booleans. Apologies for confusion

Comment: Wow! I had no idea that was the way sort was supposed to be used.
Thanks so much for your answer.

Comment: Awesome. I never thought of this. Such a subtle change and it fixes.