# Safari doesn't sort array of objects like others browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, safari

```
var myArray = [{date:"2013.03.01"},{date:"2013.03.08"},{date:"2013.03.19"}];
```

I tried:

```
function(a,b){
  return b.date > a.date;
}
```

and

```
function(a,b){
  return b.date - a.date;
}
```

The console.log in **Chrome and Firefox** give me the desired output:

```
"2013.03.19", "2013.03.08", "2013.03.01"
```

but **Safari** give the original sorting:

```
"2013.03.01", "2013.03.08", "2013.03.19"
```

Why?

Comment: What's the actual values on your objects? Strings? Date objects? The code you posted is invalid.

Comment: What is *that*? `2013.03.01` doesn't look like JavaScript.

Comment: This seems like the issue described here: [Why won't Safari 5 sort an array of objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299062/why-wont-safari-5-sort-an-array-of-objects) If not you'll likely need to post a valid jsfiddle, as your existing code is too incomplete to test.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A sort function in JavaScript is supposed to return a real number -- not true or false or a string or date. Whether that number is positive, negative, or zero affects the sort result.

Try this sort function (which will also correctly sort *any* strings in reverse-alphabetical order):

```
myArray.sort(function(a,b){
  return (b.date > a.date) ? 1 : (b.date < a.date) ? -1 : 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had digging more on that, and finally your answer work for me in safari :)

Answer (score 1):

`"2013.03.01"` is not a date.  It's a string.

In order to correctly sort by dates, you need to convert these to dates (timestamps).

```
var myArray = [{date:"2013.03.01"},{date:"2013.03.08"},{date:"2013.03.19"}];

myArray.sort(function(a,b){
    return Date.parse(b.date) - Date.parse(a.date);
});
```

You might also be able to sort them using direct string comparasions too:

```
myArray.sort(function(a,b){
    return b.date.localeCompare(a.date);
});
```