# JS sorting works in Firefox but not Safari

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari, mobile-safari

I can't understand why my script works correctly in Firefox and Chrome but not Safari. Can anyone see a possible standard language issue with the way it is coded?

```
function querysort(thisObj) {

  var type = thisObj.id;

  $('.sort-option').removeClass('selected');
  $('#'+type).addClass('selected');

  var $allRest = $('.results-entry');

  if (type === 'sort-open') {
    $allRest.hide();
    var $openRest = $allRest.filter('[data-status="open"]');
    if ($openRest.length === 0) {
        $("#no-open-shops").show();
    } else {
        $openRest.show();
    }

  } else {
    $allRest.show();
    $('#no-open-shops').hide();

    var $wrapper = $('#hit_list');
    $wrapper.find('.results-entry').sort(function (a, b) {
        if (type === 'sort-dist') {
            return +a.dataset.distance - +b.dataset.distance;
        } else if (type === 'sort-name') {
            return $(a).attr('data-cart-name') < $(b).attr('data-cart-name');
        } else if (type === 'sort-pop') {
            return $(a).attr('data-rating') < $(b).attr('data-rating');
        } else if (type === 'sort-new') {
            return $(a).attr('data-date') < $(b).attr('data-date');
        }
    }).appendTo( $wrapper );
  }
}
```

Let me add more details on the behavior that I expect (and that I see correctly on Firefox and Chrome): I have 4 buttons to click on defined in a div as:

```
  <div id="hit_list">
            <ul class="sort-nav">
              <li></li>
              <li id="sort-dist" class="sort-option">By Distance</li>
              <li id="sort-open" class="sort-option">Oopen now</li>
              <li id="sort-name" class="sort-option">By name</li>
              <li id="sort-pop" class="sort-option selected">By popularity</li>
              <li id="sort-new" class="sort-option">Most recent</li>
            </ul>
          <div id="no-open-shops">No restaurant is open</div>
```

Comment: Are you using a jQuery plugin in-conjunction with the function above? Also, you know you can use `.data()` to access the data attributes? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Comment: yes, I am using jquery.

Comment: Does it show errors in the console?

Comment: That wasn't my question. My question was, are you loading in any other jQuery plugins which maybe referencing the above function somewhere? In any regards, check the console on Safari and dump results here.

Comment: I added more code that shows how the JS is called.

Comment: I don't get console errors or warning when I click on the selectors. Simply, the Js is not responding to the input if I am on safari.

Comment: @user6358161 If you can, throw it in a fiddle.

Comment: because the code depends on a set of data, it's not trivial for me to get it to work in a fiddle. However, simply, by clicking on any of the class options above, a list of data is sorted. When I am on safari, however, some selections are simply unresponsive as if some value were not modified by the new selection.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

The following code is working based on the fact that sort should return a real number (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15507922/6358161). This achieved by using the following version of the code above:

```
function querysort(thisObj) {

var type = thisObj.id;

$('.sort-option').removeClass('selected');
$('#'+type).addClass('selected');

var $allRest = $('.results-entry');

if (type === 'sort-open') {
    $allRest.hide();
    var $openRest = $allRest.filter('[data-status="open"]');
    if ($openRest.length === 0) {
        $("#no-open-shops").show();
    } else {
        $openRest.show();
    }

} else {
    $allRest.show();
    $('#no-open-shops').hide();

    var $wrapper = $('#hit_list');
    $wrapper.find('.results-entry').sort(function (a, b) {
        if (type === 'sort-dist') {

            return (+a.dataset.distance > +b.dataset.distance) ? 1 : (+a.dataset.distance < +b.dataset.distance) ? -1 : 0;
        } else if (type === 'sort-name') {

            return ($(a).attr('data-cart-name') > $(b).attr('data-cart-name')) ? 1 : ($(a).attr('data-cart-name') < $(b).attr('data-cart-name')) ? -1 : 0;
        } else if (type === 'sort-pop') {

            return ($(a).attr('data-rating') < $(b).attr('data-rating')) ? 1 : ($(a).attr('data-rating') > $(b).attr('data-rating')) ? -1 : 0;
        } else if (type === 'sort-new') {

            return ($(a).attr('data-date') < $(b).attr('data-date')) ? 1 : ($(a).attr('data-date') > $(b).attr('data-date')) ? -1 : 0;
        }
    }).appendTo( $wrapper );
}
}
```