# Sort ascending or descending not work on safari desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, debugging, safari

In these days `safari` give me many problems... the last is about `sort()`. Is incredible for me to notice that not work only on safari (via desktop not mobile).

This is the code:

```js
 var statistiche_finali = [
   [100, 1], 
   [1200, 4.3], 
   [300, 7], 
   [2000, 9] 
 ];


 //due copie dell'array finale
 var forwards_eventi = statistiche_finali.slice(0);
 var forwards_magnitudo = statistiche_finali.slice(0);

 var forwards_eventi = forwards_eventi.sort(function(a, b) {
   return parseFloat(a[0]) < parseFloat(b[0])
 });

var forwards_magnitudo = forwards_magnitudo.sort(function(a, b) {
   return parseFloat(a[1]) < parseFloat(b[1])
 });



 console.log(forwards_eventi); 
 console.log(forwards_magnitudo);
```

i want these **outputs**

```
  //first
      [2000, 9] 
      [1200, 4.3], 
      [300, 7], 
      [100, 1], 

  //second
      [2000, 9] 
      [300, 7], 
      [1200, 4.3], 
      [100, 1],
```

Why doesn't work on `safari` ?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Comment: Look closely at [the docs for `.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). The function you give to `.sort` should return a number, *not a boolean*.

Comment: In this way return boolean ? how can i do to return number and how this code works very well with other browser ?

Comment: Try changing `<` to `-`. So it looks like `return parseFloat(a[1]) - parseFloat(b[1])`. Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507729/safari-doesnt-sort-array-of-objects-like-others-browsers)

Comment: with your suggest now works. If you write an answer i will accept it :)  thanks